# .NET 3.5CF WebRequest to Slim Framework

Tags: c#, php, rest, .net-3.5, slim

I'm writing a mobile application in .NET 3.5 Compact Framework and am trying to make a GET request to a PHP Slim Framework page. If I try to access the page from a web browser on the local machine it works, but if I try to access it from the mobile device C# application *or* the mobile device's web browser I get a HTTP 404. I made a standard PHP page to display the current time and that works on all three of the above, so isolating the problem specifically to Slim pages. I also took a look at the access.log in xampp which looks like this:

```
[20/Mar/2013:17:07:38 +0000] "GET /SlimTest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)"
[20/Mar/2013:17:09:37 +0000] "GET http://10.0.2.15/SlimTest/ HTTP/1.1" 404 523 "-" "-"
```

The first is from the local machine and the second is from the handheld device and, as you can see, the first request is completed successfully and the latter has a 404 returned to it.

The Slim PHP code looks like this:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "This is the get route";    
});
```

And the C# looks like this:

```
string webResponse = "";
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.2.15/SlimTest/");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        webResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

It is important to note that I am not a web developer so I do apologise if it is something glaringly obvious.

Speed is also of the essence with this project so even if someone could suggest an alternative RESTful PHP framework which has proven to be useful to them, then I'd very much appreciate it.

Finally, just for a quick insight, this project will have a web based application and a handheld mobile application that will communicate with a web service. I'm trying to get the web service written in PHP using slim so that it can be hosted on a Linux box to cut costs. Again, if anyone has any suggestions/alternatives then I'd be equally as grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Are you running your mobile app directly from Visual Studio or from the mobile device ?
- Are you sure that your mobile device can access the right network (10.0.2.x) ?
- Don't worry about Slim, it fits perfectly your needs